# Rescaling LAS file with lidR package in R?

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

I am trying to process a large .las file received, which appears to have been scaled in non-standard ways for some reason (likely data transfer portability). The scales between x, y, z are different in and in the range of 10^-5 instead of 0.01 or so. The odd scales in non-standard values prevents me from processing or writing the LAS files with writeLAS or other commands, with an error of:

```
Error: Invalid header: X scale factors should be factor ten of 0.1 or 0.5 or 0.25 not 1.06228168611949e-05
```

Is there a good way to actually rescale the point cloud with the lidR package?

I know that the scale factors can be accessed through the header information, as per the code and output from sample LAS file below.

I also seek additional discussion on what it means to rescale the point cloud, and what should be used for physical interpretation and writing to DEMs rather than storage.

Sample reading in and displaying header info in R:

```r
    LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
    las <- readLAS(LASfile)
    las@header
    # las@header@PHB
```

Output includes:

```
Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01
```

Currently using lidR version 2.02 and rlas version 1.3.1.

Comment: for rescaling you could use lastools >> las2las -i *.las -rescale 0.01 0.01 0.01 
https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid .las file and not corrupted somehow? Can you read it in anything else? That scale looks.... bad...

Comment: Agreed that the scale seems super bad. It manages to read and even plot in various programs (lidR, LAStools), so the las file itself appears to have valid data that shows up generally as expected. But not ruling out that the scaling is somehow incorrect or corrupt.

Comment: @zwnk the free version of lastools will mess up your data. I highly recommend steering clear of it with larger point clouds especially. The licensed version may be a different story. See this post:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118479/whats-the-deal-with-degradation-and-lastools

Comment: @rob Do you have any ground control points in the scene that is covered by your point cloud (i.e. any objects that have known coordinates)?

Comment: @Cory G `las2las` is 100% free and open source. No limitation with big data.

Comment: @JRR Thanks!!  I see that you are right after looking at the readme file. I wonder why they split that tool off from the rest of their package?

Comment: @CoryG. I don't have any easy ground control points to check as the data was provided by another agency. Depending on how this is resolved i may need to go back to them to QC the data set. Good thought though

Comment: Rob please mention your `lidR` and `rlas` version. See my edit.

Comment: Well I read your Q too quickly. I modified and added information in my A.

Comment: When this question was asked it was not a duplicate, but there since has been a very similar question with a more complete answer using up to date version o lidR. Linking duplicates helps users find the best answer. The suggested master is: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360247/rescaling-and-reoffsetting-a-photogrammetry-point-cloud-with-lidr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lidR` should not throw an error for that, at read time. It is invalid but not corrupted so it is readable. However `writeLAS` do throw an error. You have two solutions. The first one should be preferred in my opinion.

Fix your original files with `las2las` from `lastools`. `las2las` should be preferred for every tasks that imply las file processing. Use:

```
 las2las -i *.las -rescale 0.01 0.01 0.01
```

The other option, if you have already read your file in R. Fix manually the header.

```
las <- readLAS("file.las")
las@header@PHB[["X scale factor"]] <- 0.01
las@header@PHB[["Y scale factor"]] <- 0.01
las@header@PHB[["Z scale factor"]] <- 0.01
writeLAS(las, "file2.las")
```

**Edit**: `lidR 2.1.3` will have two new functions `lasrescale()` and `lasreoffset()`. See on [github](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/blob/master/R/lasrescale.R).

Comment: Thanks @JRR! In this case since the header likely just erroneous and the scaling is fine, relabelling it in R as you have works well. I also found the lastool function in the uavRst package as a wrapper for lastools if someone wanted to strictly stay within R (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/uavRst/versions/0.5-2/topics/lastool), but lastools command line works well too. Thanks again

Comment: Small additional comment, it does not cause an error at read time or during plotting with the plot function. But for writeLAS or any processing (e.g. lasfilterduplicates, lasfilterground, etc.) it does seem to throw an error.

Comment: `uavRst` is no longer a package on CRAN. For `writeLAS` it is expected. For other function it should warn only. This will be improved later.